# RegEx Pattern - Time Format

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I've a problem with a RegEx pattern and it's maddening me ;-)

Can anybody help me, please?

**My RegEx Pattern:**

```
/(\d+)?:?(\d+):(\d+)/
```

**Time-Strings:**

```
2:03, 24:35, 2:43:36
```

**Output:**

```
Array [ "2:03", undefined, "2", "03" ]  // correct
Array [ "24:35", "2", "4", "35" ]       // should be: [ "24:35", undefined, "24", "35" ]
Array [ "2:43:36", "2", "43", "36" ]    // correct
```

Comment: Seems the code for javascript. And java and javascript are not same

Comment: I'm sorry.. it was a mistake. I've corrected the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need a non-capture group surrounding your optional first digits and colon:

```
(?:(\d+)?:)?(\d+):(\d+)
```

Here is an example with it returning the results you wanted: http://www.regexr.com/3b4m2

Answer (score 0):

Use this  ([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]  HH:MM format
           ([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] HH:MM:SS format